# How to upload files and get formfields in akka-http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am trying to upload a file via akka-http, and have gotten it to work with the following snippet

```
def tempDestination(fileInfo: FileInfo): File =
  File.createTempFile(fileInfo.fileName, ".tmp")

val route =
  storeUploadedFile("csv", tempDestination) {
    case (metadata, file) =>      
      //Do my operation on the file.
      complete("File Uploaded. Status OK")
  }
```

But I'd also want to send a param1/param2 in the posted form.

I tried the following, and it works, but I am having to send the parameters via the URL (http://host:port/csv-upload?userid=arvind)

```
(post & path("csv-upload")) {
   storeUploadedFile("csv", tempDestination) {
     case (metadata, file) =>
       parameters('userid) { userid =>
          //logic for processing the file
          complete(OK)
       }
   }
}
```

The restriction on the file size is around 200-300 MB. I added the following property to my conf

```
 akka{
     http{
         parsing{
             max-content-length=200m
         }
     }
 }
```

Is there a way, I can get the parameters via the `formFields` directive ?

I tried the following

```
fileUpload("csv") {
        case (metadata, byteSource) =>
          formFields('userid) { userid =>
            onComplete(byteSource.runWith(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(metadata.fileName)))) {
              case Success(value) =>
                logger.info(s"${metadata}")
complete(StatusCodes.OK)
              case Failure(exception) =>
                complete("failure")
```

But, with the above code, I hit the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Substream Source cannot be materialized more than once
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.SubSource$$anon$13.setCB(StreamOfStreams.scala:792)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.SubSource$$anon$13.preStart(StreamOfStreams.scala:802)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.init(GraphInterpreter.scala:306)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.init(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:593)
```

Thanks,
Arvind

Comment: If you want to send the file + some data in the request body, look up `multipart/-form data`
You have this error message because `fileUpload`  consumes the request body and when `formFields` tries to read the request body, there is nothing to read (The body was already consumed (as a stream) by `fileUpload` )

Comment: Got it. I will try adding a custom processor for the `multipart/form-data`, and attempt to consume the file-stream separately, and the string parameters separately.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with sth like:

```
  path("upload") {

    formFields(Symbol("payload")) { payload =>
      println(s"Server received request with additional payload: $payload")

      def tempDestination(fileInfo: FileInfo): File = File.createTempFile(fileInfo.fileName, ".tmp.server")

      storeUploadedFile("binary", tempDestination) {
        case (metadataFromClient: FileInfo, uploadedFile: File) =>
          println(s"Server stored uploaded tmp file with name: ${uploadedFile.getName} (Metadata from client: $metadataFromClient)")
          complete(Future(FileHandle(uploadedFile.getName, uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath, uploadedFile.length())))
      }
    }
  }
```

Full example:
https://github.com/pbernet/akka_streams_tutorial/blob/master/src/main/scala/akkahttp/HttpFileEcho.scala